Bars Sorting issue in Superset
Hi this is my data for the last 1 year containing three columns: Year, Month and Count. When i am creating a bar graph using superset, the bars get arranged alphabetically instead of the order appearing in the result set. How can i do that? Please help.:
2023    Jul 3997
2023    Aug 6715
2023    Sep 6887
2023    Oct 10730
2023    Nov 9272
2023    Dec 9400
2024    Jan 11004
2024    Feb 10491
2024    Mar 13073
2024    Apr 13706
2024    May 18765
2024    Jun 15474

Last 12 months

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

same issue. seems like a bug in superset.
the legend is sorted alphabetically, instead of sorting the bar values.
have specifically set the value to sort by values of the metric & nothing responds.
